# How do I put a rectangular box around a figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, bounding-box, trimbox, pdf-with-trim

i need to put a bounding box around a cropped image of which I don't know the dimension in cm how can I do it ? 
This is the code I'm using and the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{
  positioning,
  shapes.geometric
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] () at (0,0) {\includegraphics[trim = 0cm 10cm 0cm 9cm ,clip,width=\textwidth]{file1-Oxs_MinDriver-Magnetization-00-0000500}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: this is the image im using]

Comment: Use `draw`: `\node[inner sep=0pt,draw] ....`.

Comment: It seems not to work, it is created the boarder but is not superimposed onto the image.

Comment: It does answer the question "How do I put a rectangular box around a figure?" though. I have no idea what you mean by "not superimposed" but that's a common problem with questions which load external graphics others do not have. BTW, `graphicx` gets loaded by `tikz`.

Comment: `\fbox{\includegraphics{...}}` ?

Comment: `\tcbincludegraphics{...}`, `show background rectangle` in `tikzpicture`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `current bounding box` to draw a border around it:

[image]

### Notes:

- The horizotnal lines are missing due to the `trim` that was applied (to mimick your MWE).
- You can pass in any drawing options to `\DrawBoundingBox` if you want to customize them on a per use basis.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\DrawBoundingBox}[1][]{%
    \draw [red, very thick, #1]
    ([shift={(-5pt,-5pt)}]current bounding box.south west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(5pt,+5pt)}]current bounding box.north east);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0pt] () at (0,0) {\includegraphics[trim = 0cm 1cm 0cm 1cm ,clip,width=\textwidth]{example-image}};

\DrawBoundingBox[blue]
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```